# How to write these functions in Swift 2.2?

Tags: ios, swift, function, swift2, swift3

I am trying to set up two delegates in different classes on my iOS app, however, the SDK declarations are written in Swift 3. Below is what I am trying to convert to Swift 2.2

```
func paymentMethodsViewController(_ paymentMethodsViewController: STPPaymentMethodsViewController, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error)

func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFinishWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?)

func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error)
```

I got the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'Error'"

Comment: forget Swift 2.2 go 3

Comment: @iDeveloper that site is not for Swift3 -> Swift 2.2 conversion its for Objective-c -> Swift conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
func paymentMethodsViewController(paymentMethodsViewController: STPPaymentMethodsViewController, didFailToLoadWithError error: NSError)

func paymentContext(paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFinishWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: NSError?)

func paymentContext(paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFailToLoadWithError error: NSError)
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that, but now I get the error, "Class does not conform to protocol STPPaymentMethodsViewControllerDelegate" of Stripe's SDK.

Comment: that simply means you have to use delegate methods of STPPaymentMethodsViewControllerDelegate in your class. Because you have taken the responsiablity to beacome ts delegate.

Comment: But that is another question i guess. You asked for code conversion from siwft 3 to swoft 2.2 and I did. So please accept the answer. And post a new question if you have any other issues. :-)

Comment: Alright I will. However, the function paymentMethodsViewController is what is needed to conform the class to the protocol STPPaymentMethodsViewControllerDelegate.